# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String.... but how to solve

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at hotelsystem.hotelframe.checkbox1MouseClicked(hotelframe.java:1698)
    at hotelsystem.hotelframe.access$000(hotelframe.java:15)
    at hotelsystem.hotelframe$1.mouseClicked(hotelframe.java:185)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6528)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4542)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

---

```
private void checkbox1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    double cmeal = Double.parseDouble(mealout.getText());
    double cmealp = Double.parseDouble(price1.getText());
    double cmealq = Double.parseDouble(quantity1.getText());


    if (checkbox1.isSelected()) {
        i[0] = ((cmealp * cmealq) + cmeal);
        String pmeal = String.format("%.2f", i[0]);
        mealout.setText(pmeal);
    }
}
```

Comment: `empty String` This should ring a bell.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the `parseDouble` that you are trying to do, is getting passed either an empty string or a string that cannot be formatted as a double [[doc source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)]. You should ensure that your 3 calls to `getText()` returns a non-empty string. If that cannot be done, you would want to use a `try..catch` block to take care of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have your answer in your stack trace - empty string.
To solve this, you can check if your string is empty, and if it is- don't try to format it, just set to 0 or whatever you want to do in this case.

But a better solution, if you are not sure about the string you receive, it will be to wrap it with try and catch `NumberFormatException`, for cases the string is not null, but just not a number

Answer (score 0):

```
double cmeal = Double.parseDouble(mealout.getText());  
double cmealp=    Double.parseDouble(price1.getText()); 
double cmealq= Double.parseDouble(quantity1.getText());
```

these are the three lines you are getting the exception from , there is a
chance of getting eception if you are trying to get a double from a string
begins with a whitespace `ex: "  3"` string seems like a number but its not.
check the values you are getting from the 3 tet fields first,